# Could Stackoverflow run on SQL Web Edition

Tags: sql-server, scale, high-availability

I am starting a new web venture that may need to scale to a high number of users.

I am confident with the SPLA licencing for SQL Web edition, but want to know if I will need to factor in upgrading to Standard, Enterprise or DataCenter(pretty sure it won't be this one)

I know once doesn't need to scale before they need to, but this would affect the architecture of the site and the business plan.

I know the processor limit is per physical processor, not thread, so that doesn't worry me. However some of the mirroring and backup features would worry me. Does SO rely on these features?

So the question is, could a site like Stack overflow run on SQL Web? What aspects of maintenance and high availability would be impossible to achieve?

Comment: Hm... http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx

Comment: There is a Web Edition, it's almost like standard, but has a per month $15 pricing level. Can only be used for web apps, no Cal Licensing. Question title changed to get to the point quickly, I'm more interested in what features of SQL Enterprise Stackoverflow uses.

Comment: @ShawnMelton - there is a web edition.  See http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/web.aspx

Comment: ah, sure enough forgot about that one.

Answer (score 2):

As first blush SQL Web edition is limited to 4 processors, 64 gigs of ram and a petabyte+ database size.

The real question is: *does your design require features that are not included, such as table and index partitions,  online index de-fragmentation, database mirroring, or replication?*

Without knowing more about your app, the design, the hardware, and running lots load tests it's speculative, at best, for someone to say if your site will run on a given version of SQL.

As @home pointed out you can compare version features here : http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx  Part of what you pay for in the fancier version of SQL are 'high-availability' features.  Whether SO can run on a 4 proc box with 64 gigs of ram is only part of the answer.  What happens to the site when there is a harware failure?  When maintenance needs to be done?  and so on...

With that said, if you're starting a venture based on MS technology the [Biz Spark program](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx) is a great way to get 3 years of access to all Microsoft software.  The dev licenses convert into 'go live' likenesses upon graduation.  This way you can figure out what you need, while delaying the costs till you're needs are clearer.

Answer (score 0):

EBarr is correct.

Here is some practical advice: Once you have that many customers that WebEdition is not enough for you, your business idea is working fantastically and you have no worries.

Modern hardware is so insanely fast that it can serve huge amounts of load. This was different 10 years ago.

When you max out even simple hard- and software, you are already rich.